# Range indexing in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I’m having difficulty with finding a nice way of accessing the last elements with range-indexing of a numpy array.

In MATLAB, I would do this:

`array(:,4:end)` to grab all rows and columns 4 and up.

`array[-1]` in python will grab the last element, but `array[:,3:-1]` will from my testing not grab the last column (it would find all rows and columns 4 and up, except for the very last column, which is skipped).

Does anyone know of a shorthand way of indexing the last element when range-indexing so that I don’t have to figure it out myself every time I make an array? Thanks in advance.

I tried verifying if `array[0:-1]` carries the whole array, but it does not.

Comment: this: array[:,4:]

Comment: In Python `a:b:c` is translated into a `slice(a,b,c)` object.  Missing values become `None`, thus `a:` becomes `slice(a,None,None)`.  That first None is functionally equivalent to MATLABs `end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing an array in python, the slice is *inclusive* of the start and *exclusive* of the end. So, using `arr[:, 3:-1]` will return every row and columns 4 up to but not including the last column.

If you want to slice all the way to the end, leave the stop argument blank, i.e. write `arr[:, 3:]`.